# How to organise images in a grid in a PDF generated with Apache-FOP?

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am generating PDF-s with Apache-fop. I have the following template snippet:

```
<xsl:template match="images">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="image"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="image">
    <fo:block space-after="14px">
        <fo:external-graphic content-height="200pt" height="auto" width="auto"
                             src="url('data:{type};base64,{data}')"/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

And the XML data:

```
<images>
    <image>
        <type>image/png</type>
        <data>iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS...</data>
    </image>
    <image>
        <type>image/png</type>
        <data>iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS...</data>
    </image>
    /// ... more images
</images>
```

How can I change this so the images get in a two column grid, 3x2 image each page? (Size of the images have to be assigned accordingly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***EDITED ANSWER***
I would output a line break after each 2 pictures or a page break after each 6 pictures using the operator modulo `mod` as in:

```
<xsl:template match="images">
    <fo:block><xsl:apply-templates select="image"/></fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="image">
    <fo:external-graphic 
      content-height="200pt" height="auto" width="auto" 
      padding-after="14px" 
      src="url('data:{type};base64,{data}')"/>
    <xsl:if condition="position() mod 2 = 0">
        <fo:block/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if condition="position() mod 6 = 0">
        <fo:block page-break-before="always"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

If there is no room for 3 pictures in a row, the line will break automatically after 2 pictures. In that case, it will not be necessary to break the line manually. The same can be said for the page break.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work. First of all, I got "xsl:if requires attribute: test", so I had to replace condition with test. After that it rendered the images in a single column instead of two. I think you need to remove the fo:bloc from around the image, maybe switch it to an inline element.

Comment: Indeed. Since the PO didn't provide a minimal reproducible example, I was not able to debug easily my piece of code.

Comment: I have edited my question in order to provide a more correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could put an `fo:block` containing an `fo:external-graphic` in each `fo:table-cell` of a two-column table.

Actually, you could put them all in one `fo:table-row` and specify `ends-row="true"` on every second `fo:table-cell`.

You could set the row height and column widths to get your regular 3x2 arrangement on each page.

Comment: Please write an example code, how do you put a fo:block containing an fo:external-graphic in each fo:table-cell of a two-column table?